# Why isn't it letting me convert a list into a string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am using `BeautifulSoup` to scrape the Wikipedia information box and am trying export it into a table

I want to convert my list into a BeatifulSoup in order to be able to use `.find_all` and `.find` , to look for the nested tags, but as i did not find anything online to convert, i decided to convert it into a string and then try to convert the string into beautiful soup

When I try to `.join` my string I get the error:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Tag found.

I have also tried

```
print (u'').join(unicode(row1) for fow1 in link)
print (u'').join(row1.stripped_strings)
```

but these give the error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'

```
my_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'infobox vcard'})

records = [] 

for my_tables in my_table:
    row1 = my_table.find_all('th',{'scope':'row'})
    print (row1)

    print()

    row2 = my_table.find_all('span')
    print (row2)

html = ''.join(row1)
```

It should convert the list into a string

Comment: Print returns none

Comment: Provide the url you are scraping and your expected the output.

Comment: The errors are very descriptive. Look at the beautiful soup docs. You have a list of Tags not strings. And in the other case you're trying to call join on the return of the print method.

Comment: In your code above "row2" is a list of BeautifulSoup Tag elements.
You can get the displayed text for the elements with
`for elem in row2:

  print(elem.text)`
and the HTML source with
`for elem in row2:
  print(str(elem))`

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is no longer a statement in Python 3. It's a function. This is also the case in Python 2 if you use `from __future__ import print_function` Try

```
print(''.join(str(row1) for fow1 in link))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was really stuck

Comment: It says I don't have enough reputation to upvote, I need at least 15 reputation, or am I doing something really wrong.

Comment: @Remmerton don't worry about the upvote before you get the rep for it. You should still be able to mark an answer as accepted since you asked the question though.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the big tick before.